# Angular configure or compile JSON asset

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-compiler

Is it possible in Angular or via help of a `custom-webpack` plugin to transform a JSON asset before copying it to the assets folder. I have a JSON file in which I would like to transform some values before placing it into the assets folder. I have tried to use the `CopyWebpackPlugin` but it seems that it is not applicable to assets.

What I want to do is take a JSON from the `src`, replace some values in that JSON during compilation and then put it into the target location under `dist/<...>/assets`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can actually be solved by using the `copy-webpack-plugin`. The caveat is that the Angular compiler will copy assets after the `copy-webpack-plugin` has run. The problem I was observing was that the file copied by the `copy-webpack-plugin` was overwritten by the original asset file. To ensure that the original asset template file will not overwrite the file that was copied and transformed by the `copy-webpack-plugin` the following steps are necessary:

1. Use the [asset configuration](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration) in `angular.json` to exclude the source file from the assets using the expanded asset form (optionally rename the source file to something like `foo.tpl.json` first):

   ```
   { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets", "output": "dist/assets",
     "ignore": [ "**/foo.json" ]
   }
   ```
2. Copy and transform the file via `copy-webpack-plugin`, this can be achieved using the [custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) plugin by adding the `copy-webpack-plugin` as additional plugin to the webpack configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Use it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

download link and doc link are the same

[BTW, if you need very complex query - just use **Golang** with **PostgreSQL**. No limitation there (but you have to use postgreSQL database instead of .json file then) ]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for. I only need this to compile production mode builds. At runtime the JSON is static, that is after the compilation the JSON will not change anymore. I need some solution to use configuration data, such as from environment variables and compile that into the asset. The JSON itself will be served by what ever web server the app will use.